# How to go on a specific id yii2 just like using # symbol on the same page?

Tags: php, html, css, yii2

I want to go on a specific id from another page in yii2 but it is not working properly

page 1) index.php

```
<a href = "<?= Url::to(['site/profile', 'id' => '#clients'])?>"
```

page 2) profile.php

```
<h3 id="clients">Our Clients<h3>
```

But from index page the link is not going to clients section which is located above footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this sintax  `'#' => 'name_value'` and use name not id

```
<h3 name="clients">Our Clients<h3>

<a href = "<?= Url::to(['site/profile', '#' => 'clients'])?>"
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I add smoothly scroll using jquery function how to apply same scrolling effect